# Use different post formats on different post types

Tags: custom-post-types, post-formats, add-theme-support

I added post-formats support like below.

```
add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array( 'gallery', 'link', 'quote', 'audio', 'video' ) );
```

I also added post-formats support to custom post type like below.

```
add_post_type_support( 'my-custom-post-type', 'post-formats' );
```

My question is: Is it possible to use different post formats on regular posts and custom post type?

For example, using 'gallery', 'link', 'quote', 'audio', 'video' on regular posts, and only 'gallery', 'video' on custom post type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you going in the right direction. Not my solution, slightly modified from [here](http://bluedogwebservices.com/different-post-formats-per-post-type/).

You'll need to swap out `your-post-type` for the post type you're using.

```
function adjust_post_formats() {
    if (isset($_GET['post'])) {
        $post = get_post($_GET['post']);
        if ($post)
            $post_type = $post->post_type;
    } elseif ( !isset($_GET['post_type']) )
        $post_type = 'post';
    elseif ( in_array( $_GET['post_type'], get_post_types( array('show_ui' => true ) ) ) )
        $post_type = $_GET['post_type'];
    else
        return;

    if ( 'your-post-type' == $post_type )
        add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array( 'gallery' ) );
    elseif ( 'post' == $post_type )
        add_theme_support( 'post-formats', array( 'gallery', 'link', 'quote', 'audio', 'video' ) );
}
add_action( 'load-post.php','adjust_post_formats' );
add_action( 'load-post-new.php','adjust_post_formats' );
```

Comment: Thanks @corygibbons, it works pretty well except one little thing. The fix is [here](http://bluedogwebservices.com/different-post-formats-per-post-type/#comment-45412)